# JavaScript: simple framework is not working properly

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-framework

I am trying to create a JS framework.

**Here is my JS code:**

```
function $(id)
{
  var info={
     version:1.0
  }

  if(id)
  {
    if(window === this)
    {
        console.log('window id == '+id);
        return new $(id);
    }

    console.log('id == '+id);
    this.e = document.getElementById(id);
    return this;
  }
  else{
         return info;
   }
}



$.prototype={
    controller:function(pl)
    {
       if(typeof pl.events === 'function')
       {
        console.log('event is function');
       }
    },
    click:function(callback)
    {       
        this.e.addEventListener('click', callback, false);
        return this;
    }   
};
```

**Here I am calling this Framework**

```
    <div id='test'>
        <div id='btn1'>Button1</div>    
    </div>
    <div id='btn2'>Button2</div>


    <script>            
        $('test').controller({
            events:function()
            {
                $('btn1').click(function(){
                    alert('btn1 clicked');
                }); 
            }
        }); 

        $('btn2').click(function(){
            alert('btn2 clicked');
        });             

    </script>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
window id == test
id == test
event is function
window id == btn2
id == btn2
```

The problem is **btn1** click event is not working but **btn2** click is working. Can somone suggest some solution or some better way to make a JS frame work?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with [tag:prototype.js], does it?

Comment: its native js **protoype** not what you are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is btn1 click event is not working

Well, you were not attaching a listener to it. You did pass a function to the `controller` method which could have done this, but it was never called.

```
controller: function(pl) {
    if (typeof pl.events === 'function') {
        console.log('event is function'); // but do nothing?
        // add this:
        pl.events();
    }
}
```

Comment: one more thing why **window id == test** and **id == test** both are executing inside constructer while i am using **$('test')** only once

Comment: If you call it without `new`, ie. `$('test')`, then that "window id == test" branch will execute and call `new $('test')`… Btw, you better should use `if (!(this instanceof $)) return new $(id);`.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18877343/1048572)…

Comment: but why **console.log('window id == '+id);** and **console.log('id == '+id);** both are executing when i use **$('test')**. I think only one should be executed because its ** return new $(id);** a returning statement so it should not go to next line