# Adding methods to objects

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

After coding in JS for a while I decided to make my own framework. Something similar to jQuery. But a very very stripped down version. After some googling I put together this code:

```
function $elect(id) {
    if (window === this) {
        return new $elect(id);
    }
    this.elm = document.getElementById(id);
}

$elect.prototype = {
    hide:   function () { this.elm.style.display = 'none';  },
    show:   function () { this.elm.style.display = '';      },
    toggle: function ()
            {
                if (this.elm.style.display !== 'none') {
                    this.elm.style.display = 'none';
                } else {
                    this.elm.style.display = '';
                }
            }
};
```

So far this seems to work. But I'm not interested in the functionality. I want to understand the logic. Adding methods part is understandable. Though I didn't understand the function of

```
    if (window === this) {
        return new $elect(id);
    }
```

If I remove it, function breaks. Since this is an if statement there are 2 results. `True` or `false`. So I tried to remove the if statement and just use `return new $elect(id);` assuming `window === this` returns `true`, but that didn't work. Then I thought it might return `false`, so removed the whole if statement. That also didn't work. Can someone enlighten me? Also is this code valid? I'm probably missing some stuff.

Just tested on jsfiddle and it doesn't work. Though it works on jsbin o.O

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkQbu/) [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iXitAvo/1/edit?html,js,output)

EDIT: using `$elect(id).toggle();` to call it. Though you can check the demos.

Comment: Where did you get that snippet from when you didn't understand it?

Comment: Show how you call it. I think that is the clue I am missing.

Comment: @Bergi somewhere in google? Should I post the url?

Comment: Yes please. Not only because it's wrong, but also because the author might have some explanation. And of course for correct attribution.

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me in Chrome 29.

Comment: @Bergi [This](http://www.mikedoesweb.com/2012/creating-your-own-javascript-library/) was the website.

Comment: All the functions need to `return this` so you can use them like this `$elect('theId').hide()`

Comment: @LeeMeador Originally the constructor and the methods had `return this` but I removed them after seeing it still works whether `return this` is there or not. So should I put them back? Knowing that it still works without them, what do they really do?

Comment: @akinuri: Thank you. Indeed, it is badly explained there (both what the problem is and how the solution works)

Comment: The functions will work without returning `this`, but you will not be able to chain them together as @LeeMeador described in the above comment.  The constructor doesn't need to return `this` as it already does so implicitly when called as as a constructor and, in the case of calling as a function it is explicitly returning the result of calling as a constructor.

Comment: @dc5 Oh. Just tested `$elect(id).toggle().bgColor('red');` with `return this`, it works. I didn't think about chaining the methods, but this will help a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to understand the logic.

`$elect` is a [constructor function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328449/what-difference-is-there-in-javascript-between-a-constructor-function-and-funct/) that is supposed to be called with the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) (`new $select`). If it is not (`$elect()`), what will happen then? There is no instance constructed, and the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) will point to the global object (`window`) - which we do not want. So this snippet is a guard against that occasion, when it detects that it invokes itself correctly with `new` and returns that.

> If I remove it, function breaks

When you are calling it like `$elect(id)` without the guard, it will add a `elm` property to the global object (a global variable in essence) and return nothing. Trying to call the `.toggle()` method on that will yield the exception `undefined has no method 'toggle'`.

> I tried to remove the if statement, assuming `window === this` returns true

Well, then you just created an infinite recursive function that will lead to a stack overflow exception when called.

---

Btw, the [proper way to guard against `new`-less invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367768/how-to-detect-if-a-function-is-called-as-constructor) is not to compare against `window` (the global object might have a different name in non-browser environments) and assume everything else to be OK, but to check for the correct inheritance. You want the constructor only to be applied on instances of your "class", i.e. objects that inherit from `$elect.prototype`. This is guaranteed when called with `new` for example. To do that check, you will use the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
function $elect(id) {
    if (! (this instanceof $elect)) {
        return new $elect(id);
    }
    this.elm = document.getElementById(id);
}
```

This also makes the intention of the guard explicit.

Answer (score 1):

To understand how that condition works, you must first know that in the global scope `this` refers to the `window` object. In local scope, such as within an object, `this` refers to the object itself.

Your `$elect` function is a constructor for your framework. If you call it directly, like so:

```
$elect('some-id-blah')
```

It will first realize that you are trying to create an instance (because the condition `window === this` will evaluate to true), and it will recursively create a new instance of itself. Once it does that, `this` will no longer refer to the `window` object, it will refer to the new instance of your library, thus the condition will not be met.

I hope that's somewhat understandable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the code IS returning a new instance using `return new $elect(id);`.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. My mistake :) He should be returning `this` after setting `this.elm`.

Comment: @LeeMeador - there is no reason to return `this` from a constructor - it already does so implicitly.  Using it this was works as expected without returning this: `(new $elect('textarea')).toggle();`

Comment: Up in the top comments someone says this, being a constructor, will return 'this' anyway. This explains it [Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: I deleted all my comments that were incorrect so any future reader would not have to process them in their mind. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This logic:

```
if (window === this) {
    return new $elect(id);
}
```

Ensures that, if your constructor function is called as a function:

```
var foo = $elect(id);
```

rather than as a constructor:

```
var fo = new $elect(id);
```

it will return the correct result - a new $elect object.  When called as a function, the default context will be the global context or `window` when running in the browser, triggering the `if` clause and returning the result of calling it as a constructor.

---

**Why it isn't working in your fiddle**

In the linked fiddle, it is setup to wrap your code in a `onload` handler.  The result of which looks like this:

```
window.onload=function(){
function $elect(id) {
    if (window === this) {
        return new $elect(id);
    }
    this.elm = document.getElementById(id);
}

$elect.prototype = {
    hide:   function () { this.elm.style.display = 'none';  },
    show:   function () { this.elm.style.display = '';      },
    toggle: function ()
            {
                if (this.elm.style.display !== 'none') {
                    this.elm.style.display = 'none';
                } else {
                    this.elm.style.display = '';
                }
            }
};
}
```

Because of that, your `$elect` variable isn't visible outside of the `onload` handlers scope.

Generally, you would want to add one variable to the global scope to enable access to your framework.  Something like this added at the end of your code above will make it visible:

```
 window.$elect = $elect;
```

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkQbu/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

First thing to understand is that this function is calling itself:

```
function $elect(id) {
    if (window === this) {
        return new $elect(id);
    }
    this.elm = document.getElementById(id);
}
```

First time you call the function window is going to be === this. Because there you're invoking the function as a method. When invoked as a method, functions will be bound to the object the function/method is a part of. In this example, `this` will be bound to the window, the global scope.

But then with the `new` keyword, you're invoking the function as a constructor. When invoked as a constructor, a new Object will be created, and `this` will be bound to that object, so `this` no longer refers to `window` the second time around.

With the new instance of $elect, you're then also setting a local variable elm correctly to the instance, allowing your other functions to call on that elm later.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is a constructor. By default the `this` in any function not called explicitly (`$elect()`, not `foo.$elect()`) on any other object as a method, will be passed the global object (the `window`) in `this`. However the `if` checks that if the `this` indeed refers to the `window` object, the `return new $elect(id);` is executed. The `new $elect(id)` does the following:

- make a new instance of the `$elect.prototype`
- put the newly created instance in the `this` and call the method again.

On the second pass, the `this === window` evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you call it like this:

```
$elect("theId").hide();
```

The first time in it is called as a function and will find `window === this` and do this:

```
return new $elect("theId")
```

which creates a new one and call the function again. (Whatever the 2nd invocation of the function returns will get returned.)

The second time in, it is called as a constructor, so `window !== this` and it will pass down to find the element and store it internally.

Constructor calls that don't return anything from the function itself will return the instance created.

That way the `.hide()` part will get executed with the proper value of `this` (the instance created the first time in). And the element will disappear from the screen.

Note that if you call it like this:

```
var bob = {};
bob.$select("theId").hide();
```

It will not work because the `this` is set to `bob` which gets and 'elm' property set and there is no 'hide' property to be called because its not a `$elect` kind of object.

**NOTE**

If all the other methods in the other functions return `this` you will be able to chain them:

```
$elect('theId').show().red();
```

assuming you added a function to color the element red.